# Randomly distribute objects over a surface with some clusters

Tags: 3d

I want to randomly distribute some(in thousands) objects over a surface.
This I can achieve with a function say x,y = rand().

This will evenly distribute objects over the surface, but is it possible to have some control over the randomness like having some groupings (some objects close together).

I can try to achieve this with multiple iterations of distribution, but that might run into objects overlapping.

So was looking for some kind of parameterized algorithm that might help in this area.
I do not have much knowledge in mathematics so would appreciate some help.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give some idea of how many objects you are considering? I'm wondering if a post-distribution step to move your random set around a little is feasible.

Comment: 100 to 10000 objects. Post-step is feasible, but might be time consuming as I have to move individuals objects again.

Comment: If you are working with a surface you don't want a continuous distribution to specify all three of x, y, and z.  Instead, you can have a continuous distribution specify 2 of the coordinates, and then the third one will be constrained by the first two.

Comment: Paul, i just edited my question. I meant distribution over 2 dim only (x,y)

Comment: @Joffan any ideas on how to achieve clustering in post-step?